# VS Code insists that the component is never used, even though it has been

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to import my navBar component and use it in my App.js file, however, nothing shows up when I do that, and VS code gives me a warning that the imported component has never been used.

```
import './App.css';
import navBar from './components/navBar_component';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <navBar />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Capitalize navBar, as NavBar. Lower-cased names are interpreted as built-in HTML elements (e.g. "div"), not as variables from your surrounding scope.

Comment: @Phil - That's no longer the case for newer versions of React: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Comment: Typo with `NavBar` component name, voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import React whenever you are dealing with custom Components like navBar in that case. Secondly, react strongly recommend custom Components to start with Capital letter. Like you can name your js file anything [small letter, capital letter or numbers] but while importing that file through some variable name, your varibale name should be starting with capital letter.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/navBar_component';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <NavBar />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - You just need to capitalize "navBar" as "NavBar"

---

JSX with lower-cased element names are automatically interpreted as built-in elements. e.g. `"<div>"`, `"<img>"`, etc. You can even create custom HTML elements with any name and use them in JSX, through the use of [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). To tell React that you wish to use a custom React element from your surrounding scope, you *must* make that element name start with a capital letter, this is how React distinguishes your React elements from built-in ones.

See [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for React's documentation about why React element names must be capitalized.